# How to draw a self-reference connector in OpenOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice-draw

When using a curved connector, it seems that it were unable to draw a curved ellipse/circle from a given endpoint back upon itself - with the purpose of representing a self-reference (/repeated state in a state diagram).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use **any of the other connector start/endpoints of the object as endpoint**. Assuming the starting element is a rectangle, it has four start/end points for connectors. A curved connector starting at point 1 may end at any of the other points of that rectangle; only the starting point itself isn't available as end point. In other words: starting point and end point can't be identical:
2. **Combine two or three connectors**. Two `curved connectors` are sufficient to draw a loop (`2a`). Three are required if the loop should be symmetric (`2b`).

The following LO Draw drawing demonstrates all three approaches, marking the connector's end points with arrows. Dropping the arrows as markers for the connector's ends will make the combined connectors **appear as a single drawing unit**.

[image]

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks for responding